# Numpy Broadcasting arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

As I'm trying to understand broadcasting in python, I'm coming across a shape mismatch error. I know this means that the arrays I have don't fit in terms of dimension. My code basically tries to do the following operations on the arrays with the following dimensions:

(256,256,3)*(256,256)+(256,256)

I know the problem is in the multiplication. I was wondering if there is any way to fix this? Can I add an extra dimension to the (256,256) array of the multiplication?

Comment: You can use `numpy.newaxis` to add new dimensions

Comment: see docs and examples here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say

```
A.shape = (256,256,3)
B.shape = (256,256)
C.shape = (256,256)
```

[NumPy broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) adds axes on the **left** by default, so
that would result in `B` and `C` being broadcasted to

```
B.shape = (256,256,256)
C.shape = (256,256,256)
```

and clearly that does not work and is not what you desire, since there is a shape mismatch with A.

So when you want to add an axis on the **right**, use `B[..., np.newaxis]` and `C[..., np.newaxis]`:

```
A*B[..., np.newaxis] + C[..., np.newaxis]
```

`B[..., np.newaxis]` has shape `(256,256,1)`, which gets broadcasted to `(256,256,3)` when multiplied with `A`, and the same goes for `C[..., np.newaxis]`.

---

`B[..., np.newaxis]` can also be written as `B[..., None]` -- since `np.newaxis` is `None`. It's a little shorter, but the intent is perhaps not quite as clear.